# Solution to this type of ODE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a know solution to this ODE:
$$
x= f(x) +f'(x)a(x) + f''(x)b(x);\qquad f(0)=0?
$$

Even in the case where $a,b$ are constant; I don't know how to classify or solve this type of object.  (I have very little background in ODEs).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you precise what are $t, x, f$? Also something is not coherent: $f$ is having only one variable in the differential equation and two in the initial condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine with power series expansions, it shall be solvable quite readily as both differentiation and multiplication with known power series are linear operations on polynomial spaces.

But I don't know the name of this particular differential equation.

Assume we have a truncated power series expansion for $a(x), b(x)$.

The coefficients for $a(x) : c_{a0},c_{a1},\cdots c_{aN}$

The coefficients for $b(x) : c_{b0},c_{b1},\cdots c_{bN}$

1. Build the [Toeplitz matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) which represent multiplication by these. Call them $\bf M_a,M_b$
2. Build the differential operator matrix $\bf D$. If you enumerate from $c_0$ and upwards this shall be: One off diagonal $[1,2,3,4,5\cdots,N]$
3. Express everything as a linear least squares problem in this polynomial basis.

$$\min_{\bf v}\| ({\bf I+M_aD+M_b D^2)v} - {\bf d} \|_2^2$$

Where $\bf d$ is the power series expansion for the left hand side. With the vectorization of polynomial coefficients described above will be $[0,1,0,0,\cdots,0]^t$

(in other words this $\bf d$ represents the left hand side function $x = 0\cdot 1 +1\cdot x + 0\cdot x^2 + \cdots+ 0\cdot x^N$)

Now one thing remains, to ensure $f(0) = 0$, maybe you can finish by adding it?